# Mosquitto - unable to connect from remote computer

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am trying to test a Mosquitto MQTT server.  My plan is to hopefully get it to ingest some notifications from our monitoring system in my work IT dept.  Seems perfect for the task.  I was able to install Mosquitto on a Ubuntu 20.04 server, and testing with the mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub clients worked right away (see attached screenshot).  I also was able to Google around and set up some Python script using paho mqtt module for subscribe and publish.  I set up the subscribe script as a service and it runs fine.  I can receive published messages from both mosquitto_pub and the "publish" Python script...

Now where the issues come up is when I try publishing to the Mosquitto server from a **remote computer** within my office.  For the life of me I cannot determine what the issue is. :(
I am able to telnet to the Mosquitto server on port 1883 so it does not seem to be a firewall issue on the Mosquitto server...  Whenever I try to use the publish Python script from the remote computer, it executes but it does not work -- no messages are received at the subscriber running on the server.  One odd thing is that the "on_connect" portion on the script does not work when the script is run on the remote computer; no "Connected to MQTT Broker!" message is printed when the script is run remotely. (it does work when it's run locally on the Mosquitto server).

I am attaching a screenshot of my /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf file.  I have tried all sorts of combinations on the config and each time things work when run on the server itself but not remotely.  I tried putting the IP address for the server on the config as "listener 1883 10.x.x.x".  (Note for this post using "10.x.x.x" instead of my real IP address.)  The last thing I tried was putting the adapter name, and still does not work.  As you can see I have also defined authentication (usernames, passwords) for a pubuser and subuser.  The account info does work with the mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub clients, and when used in Python scripts (when script are run on Mosquitto server) so I don't think it's an account info issue.  All signs are pointing to either some misconfiguration I have in Mosquitto, or some firewall policy in my work location.  Please help!

Please share any tips or possible fixes for me.  I might be doing something wrong in my config; please do let me know if you see something amiss.  I am a newbie with Mosquitto and MQTT but would love for it to work, kind of ruins the point if I cannot publish to the server form a remote computer though :)..

Below is example Python code I am using on the remote computer to publish (works run locally on the Mosquitto server).  I redacted the IP address of the server with 10.x.x.x).
When I run the script from the remote computer I just get "**Failed to send message to topic python/mqtt**".
:

```
import random
import time

from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client


broker = '10.x.x.x'
port = 1883
topic = "python/mqtt"
# generate client ID with pub prefix randomly
#client_id = f'python-mqtt-{random.randint(0, 1000)}'
#Set the static client id
client_id = 'python-mqtt01'
username = 'pubuser'
password = 'something'

def connect_mqtt():
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client


def publish(client):
    msg_count = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        msg = f"messages: {msg_count}"
        result = client.publish(topic, msg)
        # result: [0, 1]
        status = result[0]
        if status == 0:
            print(f"Send `{msg}` to topic `{topic}`")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to send message to topic {topic}")
        msg_count += 1


def run():
    client = connect_mqtt()
    client.loop_start()
    publish(client)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Thanks for reading!  Hopefully someone out there has encountered the same issue and fixed it!

P.S. - forgot to mention I also disabled the firewall on the Ubuntu server until I get things working (ufw disable).

Example of my default.cfg (before) removing adapter and adding log_type all:

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous false
bind_interface ens33
```

Comment: Not sure I can help - but I just ran your code connecting remotely to my mosquitto MQTT server running on a raspberry pi - and it worked perfectly. I don't have a bind_interface setting in my mosquitto config - is that interface bound to the address you're connecting to?

Comment: Thanks for checking out my post!  Yes, the ens33 interface is bound to the 10.x.x.x address.  More and more I am thinking a firewall policy in my office could be the cause of this.  I installed an older 1.6.9 version of Mosquitto from source on a different Ubuntu server and have the same issue, cannot connect remotely.

Comment: Please do not post screen shots of terminals, post the actual text. As it is those images are impossible to read.

Comment: What is shown in the Mosquitto logs? (ideally set `log_type all` in the config file). I would suggest removing the `bind_interface` while testing. Adding the output of  `sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :1883` to your question would let us confirm that Mosquitto is listening.

Comment: @Brits, thanks.  Ok I removed the interface and added log_type all in my default.conf.  After rebooting the Mosquitto server, tried testing again.  I see a bunch of errors like "1644438607: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1644438609: New connection from 10.x.x.x on port 1883."    And on the "publisher" / remote computer I see "Failed to send message to topic /python/mqtt" errors.  When I run the netstat command I got: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      850/mosquitto  (there is also a tcp6 listed for port 1883, too long to list )

Comment: Please edit your question and add these details (the sequence of events in the logs is important and the comments provide insufficient space to show this - give us a sequence that includes two disconnections). At the same time it would be nice if you could remove the screenshots (by all means include a text representation of your current `default.conf`) - see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810946) for the rationale. The logs indicate that the client is able to establish a TCP connection to the broker but the connection is dropping.

Comment: Thanks noted for future posts.  It turned out this was due to an internal firewall rule.  Our network admin allowed the traffic and the remote computer can publish now.